# Joining all subsets within a stream in Java optionals

Tags: java, option-type

This is the original piece of code:

```
Set<StatuteType> statuteTypes = registration.getStudent().getStudentStatutesSet()
    .stream()
    .map(StudentStatute_Base::getType)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I want to wrap everything in an Optional to avoid null pointers and all. If the student does not exist or the statutesSet does not exist.

What I have:

```
Set<StatuteType> statuteTypes = Optional.of(registration)
            .map(Registration_Base::getStudent)
            .map(student -> student.getStudentStatutesSet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(StudentStatute_Base::getType)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .orElse(null);
```

Would something like this be in someway possible? I want to avoid null checks in this chain, and if there's any null just return a simple null as well instead getting an exception.

Normally what I think would be logical would be to use a [flatMap as described here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-flatmap-java-examples/) but it doesn't seem to be correct in this case, because the Optional flatmap returns an Optional.

Comment: So `registration` `getStudent()`, `getStudentStatutesSet()` and `getType` can all return `null`, and you want to handle them?

Comment: Yes everything can return a null and I want to avoid having to null check everything, as there isn't really a problem when something is null. If something along the chain is null just return null. Or an empty set, haven't decided. But both work, just change the .orElse

Comment: If `registration` might be null it should be `Optional.ofNullable(registration)` instead of `Optional.of(registration)`. `Optional.of()` will throw an exception if the passed parameter is `null`.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson Thanks for the reminder, I didn't notice OP had used `of` :-)

Comment: If `student` in `.map(student -> student.getStudentStatutesSet())` is of type `Student_Base`, you can use `.map(Student_Base::getStudentStatuesSet)` instead, to match the format of the previous line.

Comment: `Optional` is not meant to be used this way. It is not supposed to replace null checks in a method chain like you are trying to accomplish. Instead, use it as a return type, if you have the chance to modify your `Registration` and `Student` classes. If you are interested in this approach, I might write an answer

Comment: @fps I disagree. I think this is a perfectly valid use of `Optional`. It's equal to the null-safe operator (`?`) in some other languages.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson Don't trust me. Instead, listen to Stuart Marks (the man from Oracle behind `Optional`) https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=1665

Comment: `.orElse(null)` is creating the null problem that you said you wanted to get rid of. Instead use `.orElse(Collections.emptySet())`.

Comment: If you want to ignore the possible nulls, simply filter the stream: `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: @fps I don't trust anyone. I agree with what is shown on the screen at the point in the video you linked to, but that is when you only have one level. Imagine 5 levels. `a.getB().getC().getD().getE()`. What alternative to an `Optional#map` chain would you suggest? 5 levels of if-null-checks? I still think this is a valid use of `Optional`. Both the API documentation and Stuart Marks says `Optional` is *primarly* intended as a method return type. That don't exclude this kind of use.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson I'm not a fundamentalist and I agree in that there should be exceptions to the rule. If you have a method chain that is 5 levels long, I think you have another problem, a design one, much more serious than using `Optional` or not. My solution would be to refactor several classes, so that there are no methods returning `null` in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
Set<StatuteType> statuteTypes = Optional.ofNullable(registration)
    .map(Registration_Base::getStudent)
    .map(student -> student.getStudentStatutesSet())
    .map(Collection::stream)
    .orElseGet(Stream::empty)    // Exit Optional, enter stream
    .map(StudentStatute_Base::getType)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

However, it does not result in a null set. Collections should never be null, only empty. I would recommend this approach. The whole point of using an `Optional` object is so you never have to deal with null values.

Comment: Perfect. But it has to be .orElse(Stream.empty()) otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: My mistake.You can use `.orElseGet(Stream::empty)` though. This won't initialize the stream unless the `Optional` is null.

Answer (score 3):

`Collection::stream` does not return an `Optional`, so you should not use `flatMap` here. You should keep using `map` on the optional.

`.map(Collection::stream)` gives you an `Optional<Stream<Statute>>`. You seem to be trying to call the *stream's* `map` and `collect` methods on this. But you need to first call `Optional.map` before you can do that.

You should also use `Optional.ofNullable` if `registration` could be null:

```
Set<StatuteType> statuteTypes = Optional.ofNullable(registration)
    .map(Registration_Base::getStudent)
    .map(student -> student.getStudentStatutesSet())
    .map(Collection::stream)
    .map(x -> // Optional.map
        x.map(StudentStatute_Base::getType) // Stream.map
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) // I assume you want to filter out the statute types which are null?
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    )
    .orElse(null);
```